# Error: Naming collision detected

Tags: react-native

when I start development server using this command:

react-native start

then I am getting error this:

Error building DepdendencyGraph:

Error: Naming collision detected: /home/awesomepankaj/Work/lifemakerProjects/workingLifemaker/LifeMaker/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/react-tools/src/shared/vendor/core/dom/focusNode.js collides with 
/home/awesomepankaj/Work/lifemakerProjects/workingLifemaker/LifeMaker/node_modules/react-native-modalbox/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/react-tools/src/shared/vendor/core/dom/focusNode.js

react-native version 0.13

Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your are stuck up here.

It is a quick fix for now.

You can delete you `react-native` folder from `node_module/react-native-router/node_module/react-native`

Instead, you can use `react-native` from `node_module/react-native`.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably because you have multiple /node_modules folders in one of your subfolders.

Comment: This one. I had a weird folder "t" in the root of my folder which was basically a copy of my node_modules folder.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the directory path like this:

```
app/
  ios/
     Pods/
        React/
           node_modules/
  node_modules/
  src/
     index.ios.js
  package.json
```

Then you can just run

```
$ ./node_modules/react-native/packager/packager.sh --projectRoots `pwd`/src --projectRoots `pwd`/node_modules
```

More detail:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3440

Answer (score 2):

For those who still have this issue or might have it, I suggest you update `npm` to the latest version, which will flatten all the modules in the `node_modules` folder, therefore reducing the risks of duplicated packages.

Answer (score -2):

If you used **CocoaPods**,you should delete you **react-native** folder from **node_module/react-native/node_module.**

My CocoaPods version is 0.39.Node version is 5.3.0.React Native version is 0.14.2.

When I deleted react-native folder,It's works.